# JQuery Cycle, how can I change from image to div?

Tags: jquery

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JQuery Cycle Plugin - Example Slideshow</title>
<style type="text/css">
.slideshow { height: 232px; width: 232px; margin: auto }
.slideshow img { padding: 15px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #eee; }
</style>
<!-- include jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- include Cycle plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.2.74.js"></script>

<!--  initialize the slideshow when the DOM is ready -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'shuffle' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slideshow">
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I make this exact scroller work with divs instead of img??

basically, I want to use
`<div> etc etc etc </div>` instead of: `<img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of a duplicate of your other question...but you just replace the images with divs. That easy.

```
<div class="slideshow">
   <div>Test 1</div>
   <div>Test 2</div>
   <div>Test 3</div>
</div>
```